# IntelliJ Idea file properties encoding

Tags: intellij-idea, encoding, properties

I added several rows in my `messages.properties` file. In intellij all shows ok, but when I pushed changes to a gitlab, something went wrong. Even in those lines in which I did not change anything, the characters were replaced by something like this:

```
file.type.not-null=\u0422\u0438\u043F \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043B\u0430 \u0434\u043E\u043B\u0436\u0435\u043D \u0431\u044B\u0442\u044C \u0443\u043A\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043D
```

What could have caused it? How can it be fixed?

My File encodings settings:
[image: My File encodings settings]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When **Default encoding for properties files** is set to UTF-8 - IDe does not change it to escape sequence. Probably you had this option set to `ISO 8859-1` before? Also if the **Transparent native-to-ascii conversion** option is enabled - IDE will automatically substitute the escape sequences and will show in Editor normal glyphs.

Comment: You you can find a stable reproducer, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with steps to reproduce and sample project.